# Is that a way break Linux user password by bypassing grub protected?

Tags: passwords, linux, grub

The best way to delve into others Linux machine is by editing the grub.

Many will start by, editing the line `ro quite splash` as `rw init=/bin/bash` during the startup (usually by pressing button `e` on the list). Second is using the recovery mode.

To secure my Linux OS I am doing two things:

1. Setting a **[GRUB](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html)** password
2. The recovery mode is disabled

After doing the 2 steps is that possible to break Linux user password by bypassing  **grub2** ?

Comment: Is the disk encrypted? If not, the easiest way to break in its booting with a live cd through the bios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, definitely.  All an attacker needs to do is boot off a live cd or usb key.  They boot into their own OS and mount your disk.